# Using DownloadString of WebClient in C# to slower when sync data

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, download, webclient

I using `select query` to get data in MSSQL and send to `DataTable`, then I using `DownloadString method` to `Post all data` got from `select from table` to my server was using MySQL.

Program work perfect, but it has a problem when only send to server few rows in many rows I was select in DataTable.
I must run again and it add to the database of server and it appear few rows. 
Just like that, If in the database have 5000 rows I must run program 6-8 times to Post all data to the server.

Why cannot send all data with 1 run program?
I think the problem in WebClient.DownloadString() method.
Here my example code:

```
DataTable dta = ListData();
foreach (DataRow r in dta.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient wcd = new WebClient())
        {
            string result = wcd.DownloadString(link + "&cmd=IMPORT&CardID=" + r["CardID"] + "&StaffID=" + r["StaffID"] + "&TransDT=" + r["TransDT"]);
            Thread.Sleep(80);
        }
    }
    catch { }

    count++;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ? Is it slower or you are getting any exception ?

Comment: It slower because I must run program many times. It run a time and stop sending data to the server.

Comment: Stop sending means, Is it hanging ? It is also possible that the some exception might have thrown, but it is not processed in your code. put some prints in catch block and check.

Comment: It not throw any exception.

Comment: hm.. So you are saying after some iterations wcd.DownloadString() is hanging.. You can add print before and after and determine approximate time/iteration, the statement is hanging.We may get some clue about the issue. During that time just check performance of the system also.  Is there any restriction at web server side(where you are posting data)?

Comment: Thank you very much @Venkatesh. I think it happing in my web server.

Comment: Good that you root caused!..